# how do i rectify the undefined output for this.Status?

Tags: javascript

My AJAX code for a reqres server doe not display the desired output or it does not update the default text when hit on submit.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sntLR.png)

And when i try to print the value of this.Status, in shows undefined on the chrome console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reMWz.png)

and when i remove the this.Status condition from the if statement, i get the desired output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsuzN.png)

what could be the reason and how do i rectify it?
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`XMLHttpRequest.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) is lower case (JavaScript is case sensitive like most of the languages)